# my Fragment not getting executed to onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to implement a menu to get displayed from *Fragment*

```
public class NewsTab extends Fragment {
```

but the below code doesn't seem to execute.

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.newsmenu, menu);
        TextView text= null;

        SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                Log.e("search sering....:", newText.toString());
                dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
                dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
                    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                        Log.e("searched ....:", constraint.toString());
                        return db.fetchOrdersByName(constraint.toString());
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }`
```

I've used `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in the `onCreate` method.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_summary_tab, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);

        if (menuVisible) {
            Log.e("SetMenuVisibleFragmentA", menuVisible + " ");
        }
    }
```

I've been trying to get it work since couple of days but nothing is working. I do not know what is missing here. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems almost OK.

1. Try using `menu.clear()` in your `onCreateOptionsMenu()` before inflating fragment menu `newsmenu`.
2. Put some log in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` to know if the method is not being called.

**Update `onCreateOptionsMenu()` as below:**

```
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        menu.clear()

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.newsmenu, menu);
        TextView text= null;

        SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                Log.e("search sering....:", newText.toString());
                dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
                dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
                    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                        Log.e("searched ....:", constraint.toString());
                        return db.fetchOrdersByName(constraint.toString());
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: thank you. Even with menu.clear(); it's didn't show the menu. I noticed it is not even entering into the method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu.. I put the same oncreateoptionsmenu(....)method in my mainactivity  "public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{ " to see if it can display the menu items. But there also that code is not getting executed. I do not know where am I doing the mistake. '